# What is the format of compose links mail clients such as Exchange,AOL,Yahoo,Outlook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

I am new to IOS.I am trying to open another app from my app to send mail so i got URL schema and format to open gmail app but I am not aware of the formats to open Exchange,AOL,Yahoo,Outlook so that I can check whether that app is available in device are not and if it is available I will send mails from that if app is not available I will give a alert that app is not installed. below is the code for gmail. Can any one help me out with formats of Exchange,AOL,Yahoo,Outlook  like i did for  gmail "googlegmail:///co?" so that I can implement the UI manually like image below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mj0n.jpg)

```js
 NSString *customURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"googlegmail:///co?subject=%@", subject];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[customURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
    else {
        
        NSLog(@"Application is not installed");
        
        //not installed, show popup for a user or an error
        }
```

Comment: This link maybe help you http://handleopenurl.com/scheme

Comment: for yahoo mail use **yaxis://** and also this link will be help http://lightarrow.com/lifetopix/launch-urls-for-popular-apps

Comment: Thank you so much this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

first of All you Need a iPhone Device to Run Email Code.Email can not be send through Simulator.
And here is the link http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-create-email-attachment/
Good Tutorial For Sending Email in iOS and also a discussing a good format and all the steps i think it may be helpful for u.thanks.